# What's the difference between Screwjack and Ball screw?

Tags: aircraft-design

Flaps are driven by screw jacks or ball screw ?

Comment: The text of your question and the posted question ask two different questions.  Are you really asking about both?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean

Comment: A ballscrew is one fancy type of screw you could use in making a screw jack, so the question is a bit meaningless, not to mention far too broad.

Comment: A ball screw is a type of jack screw. I'm guessing you are looking for the difference between a Ball Screw and an ACME Screw. Where each are used is dependent on the aircraft. Boeing designed jets all use Ball Screws everywhere. MD liked to use ACME screws.

Answer (score 8):

A ball screw uses round bearing balls inbetween the screw shaft and the sliding nut it engages to transfer the forces between them, with a minimum of friction. The spiral grooves cut into the shaft and the nut are contoured to accomodate and hold in place the balls between them. A screw jack has the threads cut into the rotating shaft in direct contact with the threads cut into the slider nut. The ball screw mechanism is more precise, resistant to wear, and easier to move but more expensive than the screw jack.

Comment: All true, but which system is actually utilized for flap deployment?  And on which type of aircraft?  While the answer evaluates different methods of flap actuation, it doesn't answer the text of the question.

Comment: I answered the question posed in the title. My answer is an accurate answer to that question and does not deserve a downvote.

Comment: Agreed -- you answered the question in the title, however, the question asked in the post is unique from the question in the title.

Comment: @Marius - the question in the body of the question is obviously too broad, as it is inconceivable that this has not varied between aircraft.  Probably it should be closed.

Comment: Or perhaps slimmed down to a single kind of aircraft, as an example.  That said, if the OP isn't going to come back and do something about it, I'd move for closure.

Also, for reference, I removed my downvote after the first couple comments.

Comment: this question has generated a surprising amount of interest (as measured, perhaps inaccurately, by the score that the answer has accrued), even if the OP's statement of it may have been too broad or unclear.

Comment: Don't forget that ACME screws are self-locking. Where each is used depends on the aircraft and more generally the OEM. Boeing doesn't use ACME screws, while MD loved them.